# Python - Unicode to something split-able

Tags: python, unicode, split

I need to break a date value down to it's elements ( `8/23/2011` ) which should be a piece of cake with

```
 variable.split("/")
```

but it tells me that

```
'unicode' object has no attribute 'Split'
```

I tried encoding it as a different format:

```
date.encode("utf-8")
```

then it tells me that

```
'str' object has no attribute 'Split'
```

As A newbie to Python it seems like I've used split with strings before, but am not getting it to the right format or something.  Or perhaps there is another way that is even easier.

Comment: Note: if you're parsing a date, there's the `datetime.strptime` function to do it neatly. http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/datetime#strftime-and-strptime-behavior

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Python is case-sensitive; you want `split`, not `Split`.

```
>>> x = u"8/23/2011"
>>> x.Split('/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'unicode' object has no attribute 'Split'
>>> x.split('/')
[u'8', u'23', u'2011']
```

Answer (score 1):

Python is case-sensitive. The method is called `split`, not `Split`.

Answer (score 0):

`unicode.split` starts with a lower-case `s` and works fine:

```
>>> u'a,b'.split(u',')
[u'a', u'b']
```